# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException spring websphere

Tags: spring, websphere

I need help fixing this error I get when trying to deploy my ear application into WebSphere,
it start in local but not on server

any help would be much appreciated. Here is the error log

`java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 0x4942f896 No; nested exception is: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: 
Unable to read value from underlying bridge : Mismatched serialization UIDs : 
Source (RepId RMI:org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:EB57AF4A0F53C5BA:
1A382F46FCF3E33C) = 1A382F46FCF3E33C whereas Target (RepId RMI:org.springframework.beans.factory.
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:EB57AF4A0F53C5BA:E64C86E7C9689EA8) = E64C86E7C9689EA8 vmcid: IBM minor 
code: 896 completed: No`